# Set class on a tag after click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have the following code. 
I wonna set a css class on the a tag that is clicked. But i wonna do it only in the language div. How can i do that? When i try to do it with $("language a") is doesn't do anything.

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="language">
    <a href="#" class="">test 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="">test 2</a>
 </div>
    <a href="#" class="">No div 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="">No div 2</a>
</div>

$("a").click(function(event){
   $("a.active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});

.active {font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: The correct selector for an id has a hash _(#)_ in front of it `$("#language a")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$( "#language a" ).click( function() {
    $( "#language a.active" ).removeClass( "active" );
    $( this ).addClass( "active" );
});
```